# How to evaluate the integral $\int_1^9\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{81-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals

So I was recently looking at a new book on Calculus<sup>[1]</sup> that I got and decided to look at the techniques for integration that it listed. I then decided after a while to make my own integral and evaluate it using the techniques that it listed. Here is the integral I came up with<sup>[2]</sup>:$$\int_1^{9}\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{81-x^2}}$$which I thought that I might be able to evaluate. Here is my attempt at doing so:

---

We use the substitution $x=9\sin(\theta)\implies\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac x9\right)$, and then we can have $dx=9\cos(\theta)d\theta$, and then $\sqrt{81-x^2}$ becomes<sup>[3]</sup>$$\sqrt{81-81\sin^2(\theta)}=9\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}\implies9\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)}\implies9|\cos(\theta)|=\sqrt{81-\dfrac{x^2}9}$$$$\because|\cos(\theta)|=\sqrt{a^2-\dfrac{x^2}a}\because\text{the inverse sine function}$$$$\text{oscillates between }-\dfrac\pi2\text{ and }\dfrac\pi2\text{ which implies}$$$$\cos(\theta)=|\cos(\theta)|=\sqrt{a^2-\dfrac{x^2}a}=\sqrt{81-\dfrac{x^2}9}$$This implies the integral $I(t)$ is now$$\int_1^9\dfrac{\require{cancel}\cancel{9\cos(\theta)}d\theta}{9\sin(\theta)\cancel{(9\cos(\theta))}}$$$$=\dfrac19\int_1^9\csc(\theta)d\theta$$Now there’s only one problem: Here’s what we get when we evaluate the integral:$$\dfrac19\left[\operatorname{Ln}\left(\sin\left(\dfrac\theta2\right)\right)-\operatorname{Ln}\left(\cos\left(\dfrac\theta2\right)\right)\right]_1^9$$There’s only one problem. I know how to evaluate any $\sin(\dfrac x2)$, but I don’t know how to evaluate any $\cos(\dfrac x2)$. Then, I decided to go back in the book to the part on trigonometric functions and saw definition (**$16.13$**):

> (**$16.13$**)$\quad\cos^2(u)=\dfrac{1+\cos u}2$

This was great because now I could finally integrate the function. Then,$$\dfrac19\left[\operatorname{Ln}\left(\sin\left(\dfrac\theta2\right)\right)-\operatorname{Ln}\left(\cos\left(\dfrac\theta2\right)\right)\right]_1^9$$$$=\dfrac19\left[\ln\left(\sqrt{\dfrac12(1-\cos(\theta))}\right)-\ln\left(\sqrt{\dfrac12(1+\cos(\theta))}\right)\right]_1^9$$$$\dfrac1{18}\left[\ln\left(\dfrac{1-\cos(\theta)}2\right)-\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\cos(\theta)}2\right)\right]_1^9$$$$\implies\dfrac1{18}\left[\ln\left(\dfrac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}\right)\right]_1^9$$$$\implies\dfrac1{18}\left[\ln\left(\dfrac{9-\sqrt{81-x^2}}{9+\sqrt{81-x^2}}\right)\right]_1^9$$which converges to$$-\dfrac1{18}\ln\left(\dfrac{(9-\sqrt{80})^2}{161}\right)$$or approximately $0.603108$

---

#### My question

---

Did I evaluate the integral correctly, or what could I do to evaluate it correctly?

---

##### Notes

---

<sup>[1]</sup>Calculus by Elliot Mendelson, PHD.

<sup>[2]</sup>Based off of Chapter $32$ “Techniques of Integration II” example $32.12$

<sup>[3]</sup>This is done using Strategy II: “If $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ occurs in an integrated, try the substitution $x=a\sin\theta$.”

Comment: The limits for $\theta$ are not $1$ and $9,$ but $\sin^{-1}(1/9)$ and $\pi/2.$

Comment: The final denominator should be $1$ instead of $161.$

Comment: Apart from this, everything is correct. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2Cx%5Csqrt%5C%28123%2981-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2C9%7D%5D The result is approximately $0.32081.$ https://www.google.com/search?q=-%28ln%289-sqrt%2880%29%29%29%2F9

Comment: fwiw, your computations include a term of the form $$\log\frac{1-z}{1+z}$$, which would suggest that the **inverse hyperbolic tangent** is a good candidate for finding the closed form antiderivative for your initial expression. for example, see the derivative taken in WolframAlpha [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+arctanh%28sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally most of this is correct.

---

The biggest error comes in the very last computation:
$$
-\left. \dfrac1{18}\left[\ln\left(\dfrac{9-\sqrt{81-x^2}}{9+\sqrt{81-x^2}}\right)\right] \right|_{x=1} \ne -\dfrac1{18}\ln\left(\dfrac{(9-\sqrt{80})^2}{161}\right)
$$
To see this, note that
$$
\left. \dfrac{9-\sqrt{81-x^2}}{9+\sqrt{81-x^2}} \right|_{x=1}
= \frac{9-\sqrt{80}}{9+\sqrt{80}}
$$
which I'm sure you realized. Multiplying by $9-\sqrt{80}$ on top and bottom to rationalize, we get
$$
\frac{9-\sqrt{80}}{9+\sqrt{80}} \cdot \frac{9-\sqrt{80}}{9-\sqrt{80}}
= \frac{(9-\sqrt{80})^2}{9^2 - (\sqrt{80})^2}
= \frac{(9-\sqrt{80})^2}{81-80}
= (9-\sqrt{80})^2
$$
(whereas you *added* on bottom). One can then simplify to conclude a final answer of
$$
- \frac 1 9 \ln \left(9 - \sqrt{80}\right)
$$
Note that [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28integral+from+1+to+9+of+dx%2F%28x+sqrt%2881-x%5E2%29%29+%29+-+%28+-+1%2F9+ln%289+-+sqrt%2880%29%29%29) agrees (up to rounding error and algebraic manipulation, since it chooses a slightly different form).

---

Throughout, you should change your bounds after shifting to $\theta$ as well. For instance,
$$
\int_1^{9}\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{81-x^2}}
\ne \dfrac19\int_1^9\csc(\theta)d\theta
$$
but instead
$$
\int_1^{9}\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{81-x^2}}
\ne \dfrac19\int_{\arcsin(1/9)}^{\pi/2} \csc(\theta)d\theta
$$
This also prevents the need to convert back to $x$. Of course, if one wishes to insist on this style of writing, they should at least specify the variable in the bounds, if just for clarity and bookkeeping purposes. For instance,
$$
\int_1^{9}\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{81-x^2}}
= \dfrac19\int_{x=1}^{x=9} \csc(\theta)d\theta
$$
is an equality I would take less issue with.

One can say essentially the same about the case of evaluations.

---

*Anecdotally, I would suggest getting very familiar with the `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` environment in MathJax/LaTeX, because it would make your post and your code a lot cleaner.*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with PrincessEev that

$$
I=\frac{1}{9} \int_{\sin ^{-1} \frac{1}{9}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csc \theta d \theta
$$

and try to give a complete solution to it using the result that
$$
\int \csc \theta d \theta=-\ln |\csc \theta+\cot \theta|+C
$$
then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\frac{1}{9}[\ln |\csc \theta+\cot \theta|]_{\sin ^{-1} \frac{1}{9}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
& =-\frac{1}{9}[\ln |1+0|-\ln |9+4 \sqrt{5}|] \\
& =\frac{1}{9} \ln (9+4 \sqrt{5})
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!