# Integrate $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I want to integrate

\begin{equation*}
\int_{a}^b\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx 
\end{equation*}

by using the substition $\varphi(t)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. For sake of simplicity we assume $0< a< b< 1$. If we consider the constant function $f(x)=1$, then we get

\begin{equation*}
\int_a^b\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_{a}^{b}(-1)\cdot f(\varphi(t))\varphi(t)'dt=\int_{\varphi(a)^{-1}}^{\varphi(b)^{-1}}(-1)\cdot 1dt=\sqrt{1-a^2}-\sqrt{1-b^2}. 
\end{equation*}
Is this correct? It feels strange to use $f(x)=1$ but I don't see that it violates any conditions, don't it?

Comment: Incidentally, I left a related [**comment**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756385/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-19-fracdxx-sqrt81-x2#comment10096184_4756385) just yesterday on MSE! You might find the linked problem there of interest. As it happens, this particular antiderivative is amenable to the **inverse hyperbolic tangent**; see e.g. WolframAlpha [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx+-arctanh%28sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29).

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule saying you cannot use $f(x)=1$. The only thing missing in the proof above is to show how you know that

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = -f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)$$

is in fact true.

---

Then again, if you found a function, $F$, such that $F'=f$, then you don't really need to use a "substitution" method if you want to calculate $$\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ since the fundamental theorem of calculus already tells you that the above value is just $F(b)-F(a)$.

Comment: It is the point in finding the antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. The same phenomenon will happen any time that the variable $\phi$ you choose for your substitution happens to be the antiderivative of the integrand.

Alternatively, substituting $$u = 1 - x^2, \qquad du = - 2x \,dx$$
transforms the integral to
$$-\frac{1}{2} \int_{1 - a^2}^{1 - b^2} \frac{du}{\sqrt u} = -\left.\sqrt{u}\right\vert_{1 - a^2}^{1 - b^2} .$$

Answer (score -1):

Let's first consider the integral without limits:

$$
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx.
$$

Now substitute:

$$
\phi(x) = x^2.
$$

Then it holds:

$$
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\phi(x)}} \, d\phi(x).
$$

The second integral can be integrated normally to:

$$
= -\sqrt{1-\phi(x)} + C.
$$

Now substitute back to:

$$
= -\sqrt{1-x^2} + C.
$$

It is therefore valid:

$$
\int_a^b \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx = \left[-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]_a^b,
$$

and therefore:

$$
= -\sqrt{1-b^2} + \sqrt{1-a^2}.
$$

This is valid for $0 < a < b < 1$.

Comment: Please MathJaxify $\implies$
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/316749 .
Much progress will be achieved by replacing the brackets with $ signs.